# Get flat array of values from a specified column of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that contains 4 arrays with one value each.

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(19) "test01@testmail.com"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(19) "test02@testmail.com"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(19) "test03@testmail.com"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["email"]=>
    string(19) "test04@testmail.com"
  }
}
```

What is the best (=shortest, native PHP functions preferred) way to flatten the array so that it just contains the email addresses as values:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "test01@testmail.com"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "test02@testmail.com"
  [2]=>
  string(19) "test03@testmail.com"
  [3]=>
  string(19) "test04@testmail.com"
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In PHP 5.5 you have [`array_column`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$plucked = array_column($yourArray, 'email');
```

Otherwise, go with [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$plucked = array_map(function($item){ return $item['email'];}, $yourArray);
```

Comment: Or if you don't have PHP 5.5, you can use the userland implementation of `array_column` https://github.com/ramsey/array_column by the author of the official function

Comment: Since PHP 7.4 you can use arrow function to make it more compact: `$plucked = array_map(static fn($item) => $item['email'], $yourArray);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) . This can flatten up even multi-nested arrays.

```
<?php
$arr1=array(0=> array("email"=>"test01@testmail.com"),1=>array("email"=>"test02@testmail.com"),2=> array("email"=>"test03@testmail.com"),
    3=>array("email"=>"test04@testmail.com"));
echo "<pre>";
$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr1));
$new_arr = array();
foreach($iter as $v) {
    $new_arr[]=$v;
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

**`OUTPUT:`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => test01@testmail.com
    [1] => test02@testmail.com
    [2] => test03@testmail.com
    [3] => test04@testmail.com
)
```

Comment: Also nice approach, but I prefer @moonwave99's answer as it is a lean one liner.

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel, No problem. I suggested this as a generalized solution as this will work even on multidimensional arrays.